# Firebase Cloud Storage 'getDownloadUrl' Not Working With Ionic 'capacitor://localhost' iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

#### Operating System

iOS 16.5

#### Browser Version

Capacitor iOS WebView

#### Firebase SDK Version

9

#### Firebase SDK Product:

Storage

#### Describe your project's tooling

Ionic Angular Capacitor

#### Describe the problem

No output for `getDownloadUrl` when served from `capacitor://localhost` (native app) when running command 'ionic cap build ios' and running the project from Xcode but works from `http://localhost` when running command 'ionic cap run ios -l --external --open '

I tried using then/catch and tried try/catch with no hope, and checked the source code of the library and seems the lib doesn't through an error if there. I tried to edit the lib from node_modules but with the build process of tree shaking, minification, uglification, and removing console.logs() that was super hard. I know that Google mustn't support strange protocols like capacitor://localhost but that how 30% of the market apps uses right now, can I get little help please what is going wrong? maybe some whitelisting maybe some storage permissions? I spent 10 hours straight debugging this, but with no good news...

#### Steps and code to reproduce issue

in 'http://localhost'

```js
getDownloadURL(storageRef)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res); //working
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err); //no output
          });
```

in 'capacitor://localhost'

```js
getDownloadURL(storageRef)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res); //no output
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err); //no output
          });
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is fixed in the latest angular-fire version,
you can use it and this will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Capacitor HTTP to patch fetch and XHR requests? that might be the issue.. check if you have the following block in your capacitor.config.ts file plugins section

```
CapacitorHttp: {
  enabled: true,
},
```

if yes, remove it and try. When capacitor is patching the Firebase XHR request its casuing some issue which returns error. Same is discussed in the [Thread Here](https://github.com/capacitor-community/background-geolocation/issues/101)

Comment: I tried enabling it and also disabling it but with no hope :(